# mistakenly installed ImageMagick on Debian - how to remove it?

Tags: debian

I went to install imagick PECL extension on debian. I mistakenly installed ImageMagick with 75 MB unnecessary dependencies. Could someone please help me and tell me the simplest way to remove it all and return back the 75 MB

```
<code>apt-get install imagemagick
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  fontconfig fonts-droid ghostscript gsfonts hicolor-icon-theme
  imagemagick-common libavahi-client3 libcairo2 libcups2 libcupsimage2
  libdatrie1 libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21 libexiv2-12 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgs9 libgs9-common libice6 libijs-0.35 libilmbase6
  libjasper1 libjbig0 libjbig2dec0 liblcms1 liblcms2-2 liblensfun-data
  liblensfun0 liblqr-1-0 libmagickcore5 libmagickcore5-extra libmagickwand5
  libnetpbm10 libopenexr6 libpango1.0-0 libpaper-utils libpaper1 libpixman-1-0
  librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsm6 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff4 libwmf0.2-7
  libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxft2 libxrender1 libxt6 netpbm poppler-data
  ufraw-batch x11-common
Suggested packages:
  ghostscript-cups ghostscript-x hpijs imagemagick-doc autotrace cups-bsd lpr
  lprng enscript ffmpeg gimp gnuplot grads hp2xx html2ps libwmf-bin mplayer
  povray radiance sane-utils texlive-base-bin transfig xdg-utils cups-common
  exiv2 libjasper-runtime liblcms-utils liblcms2-utils ttf-baekmuk
  ttf-arphic-gbsn00lp ttf-arphic-bsmi00lp ttf-arphic-gkai00mp
  ttf-arphic-bkai00mp librsvg2-bin poppler-utils fonts-japanese-mincho
  fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-japanese-gothic fonts-ipafont-gothic
  fonts-arphic-ukai fonts-arphic-uming fonts-unfonts-core ufraw
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fontconfig fonts-droid ghostscript gsfonts hicolor-icon-theme imagemagick
  imagemagick-common libavahi-client3 libcairo2 libcups2 libcupsimage2
  libdatrie1 libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21 libexiv2-12 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgs9 libgs9-common libice6 libijs-0.35 libilmbase6
  libjasper1 libjbig0 libjbig2dec0 liblcms1 liblcms2-2 liblensfun-data
  liblensfun0 liblqr-1-0 libmagickcore5 libmagickcore5-extra libmagickwand5
  libnetpbm10 libopenexr6 libpango1.0-0 libpaper-utils libpaper1 libpixman-1-0
  librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsm6 libthai-data libthai0 libtiff4 libwmf0.2-7
  libxcb-render0 libxcb-shm0 libxft2 libxrender1 libxt6 netpbm poppler-data
  ufraw-batch x11-common
0 upgraded, 55 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 25.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 75.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?</code>
```

Comment: ImageMagick / GraphicsMagick are just by a ton of programs. Just keep it. Chances are the next program you install will depend on it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `dpkg -L imagemagick` and make note of the files in that package.
2. Run `apt-get remove imagemagick` to remove the package.
3. Run `dpkg -L imagemagick` again to see if the files still exist.

Comment: If I run `apt-get remove imagemagick` it will only remove imagemagic: "After this operation, 429 kB disk space will be freed."

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get remove imagemagick-common
```

It removes 95 Mb for me after `apt-get remove imagemagick`.

Answer (score 0):

To just remove a package, you do:

```
apt-get remove <package-name>
```

However, if you want to have eradicated, then you do:

```
apt-get purge <package-name>
```

Now, when a package gets installed because you install another, that's a dependency so you do not want to remove it.

Answer (score -2):

Well, I did `apt-get remove` package by package.